# Load on host server and server restart 

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My web hosting service has a problem with my website's SQL query. Apparently the SQL query is causing the server to restart. After some time it will automatically restart the server and I can see my website.

Can the load from my SQL query affect the server?

If you look at my website, [www.websofindia.com](http://www.websofindia.com), it's so nice and so speedy. So where is the problem?

Google Analytics shows my users are daily 600 to 700+. My PHP version is 5.2

Answer (score 1):

Ask your host for a copy of the mysql slow queries log or the error log (hostname.err) from the server at the time of the crash.

If they don't know what these are, or cannot produce them, you should probably find another host.